# How do ORM's implement type-safe queries?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, dao

How do ORM's like Java's Hibernate or PHP's Doctrine actually implement type checking? I'm implementing a small POC ORM/DAO for a read-only in-house DB and I'm beginning to investigate on how to actually get type safety to work.

I have model classes similar to

```
@Table(name = "baseballStats")
public class BaseballStatistic extends PinotModel {

public static final Find FIND = new Find<BaseballStatistic (BaseballStatistic.class) {} ;

@Column(name = "playerID")
private String _playerID = null;

@Column(name = "playerName")
private String _playerName = null;

@Column(name = "teamID")
private String _teamID = null;

@Column(name = "numberOfGames")
private String _numberOfGames = null;
}
```

and a query generator mostly working except for the type-checking aspect.

Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by type checking? It is your responsibility as a developer of entity class to make sure that type of property in entity class matches type of column in database. You will get `ClassCastException` otherwise

Comment: Yes that is true, but in the case that they don't, shouldn't the framework actually notify that with a compiler error or some sort of warning that the types are mismatched with the type stored in the db? Is there a way of doing this without storing a copy of the table properties?

Comment: How can framework check database structure during compilation? It at least needs to connect to that database and for that it needs user/pass and connection URL.

Comment: If that is the case, what do other ORMs like Ebean actually mean when they say that they are type safe
http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/query/background/typesafe

Comment: Looks like they only check that parameters passed to query actually compatible with type of proeprties of java classes `Using query beans means that the bind values used for any given property must be compatible with the properties type`. Like you cannot search for a person with age greater then `qwerty`, it will ask for an integer or long value for age parameter.

Comment: ah i see, so it basically only looks at the query and then checks the type against the model. got it, thanks!